# Advanced Inequality with Floor Functions

Tags: inequality, optimization, ceiling-and-floor-functions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For positive real numbers $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ and $d,$ find the minimum value of
$$\left\lfloor \frac{b + c + d}{a} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{a + c + d}{b} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{a + b + d}{c} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{a + b + c}{d} \right\rfloor.$$

I'm not seeing a technique to easily solve this problem; at this moment, I'm thinking a property of some basic inequalities such as Cauchy or AM-GM will help. Other than that, I really have no idea. Solutions?

Comment: If same expression was given without the floor functions, what'd have been the minimum value?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I tried *this*", but either give your working or explain why your idea did not work.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\left[\frac{a+b+c}{d}\right]>\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b+c}{d}-4=\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a}-8\geq16-8=8.$$
Now, make an example for $$\sum_{cyc}\left[\frac{a+b+c}{d}\right]=9.$$

I got that $(a,b,c,d)=(5,5,5,4)$ is valid.

Comment: It's a duplicate (found within seconds with Approach0).